# Windows - can't run a node.js app as a background service with npm-windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, service, vbscript

I am trying to use node-windows to run my script as a background service.

I installed node-windows with the global flag, and then linked.

service.js:

```js
var Service = require("node-windows").Service;

console.log("entered");

// Create a new service object
var svc = new Service({
  name: "myService",
  description: "my service",
  script:
    "C:\\path-to-my-script\\example.js",
});

// Listen for the "install" event, which indicates the
// process is available as a service.
svc.on("install", function () {
  console.log(" entered install ");
  svc.start();
});

// Listen for the "start" event and let us know when the
// process has actually started working.
svc.on("start", function () {
  console.log(
    svc.name + " started!\nVisit http://127.0.0.1:3000 to see it in action."
  );
});

svc.on("error", function () {
  console.log(svc.name + " error occured");
});

svc.install();

console.log(" completed");
```

example.js:

```js
var http = require("http");

const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  res.end("Hello World");
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

After `node service.js`, I receive the following error:
`Windows Script Host: There is no script engine for file extension ".vbs"`

I already tried the following:

- in cmd: `assoc .vbs=VBSFile`

Still nothing happens.

Comment: have you installed node-windows globally? (-g flag)
have you run this command? npm link node-windows

Comment: What does `example.js` contain?

Comment: @RaphaelBenHamo I did that, yes.
I don't think the problem is with the node-windows, since it created some 'daemon' folder with `myservice.exe`, `myservice.exe.config` and `myservice.xml` inside
@user692942 I updated the description

Comment: Glad you worked out the problem, but where in any of that is a VBScript file run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the default program for handling `.vbs` scripts was set to *Notepad++*, instead of *Microsoft Windows Based Script Host*. (You can see yours under Settings/Default apps/Choose default apps by file type).

To revert it back , I [found this as the only solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1108349/change-default-program-for-opening-vbs-files).

Comment: Your solution should not be dependent on file associations. Run wscript.exe or cscript.exe with your script as a parameter to avoid any file association issues.

Comment: There are also easier ways to run a script in the background with elevated privileges (e.g. Task Scheduler) but maybe you have other reasons for using node.js?